# Building a Rolling Wall, Step 1 The Base

Tags: plywood, strength

I am working on a project to create a rolling wall for a local art gallery.

Wall will be 8ft wide, 7ft tall and 1-1/2ft deep. I'm planning to frame it with 2x4s as a standard wall, mounted on top of a metal & OSB cart, and sheathed in OSB (rather than drywall)

Here is a link to an inspiration buildout video:

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=E3SrGzAsRBE

Now to the question.

For the base cart, I am unsure what metal to use.

I have watched DIY videos that suggested welding 2x2 square steel tube to make the frame and securing plywood or OSB to the surface. I think this may be overkill, and I don't have access to welding capabilities.

As an alternative I am exploring:
Building the frame out of angles slotted steel beams and securing this to 7/16th sheet of OSB.

My biggest concern is the 8 foot span between the castors.

I will Of course be mounting 2x4 As a part of the framed walls baseplate. So this will further add to the strength.

Looking to the community here to provide some guidance:

- Is the 2x2 Welded square steel tube Overkill?
- Would the angles slotted steel be sufficient?
- Am I just over engineering this whole thing and should drop the metal all together an build the frame out of 2x4, top it with OSB, then frame the wall on top?

As a secondary question:
Based on your recommendation what method of fasteners should I use for the OSB to metal.

Comment: I don't know that you can get a definitive, satisfactory, answer to this kind of query without some back and forth, which is pretty much specifically outside the scope of SE. But *just as a general thing*, there's no reason something of this type couldn't be made entirely from wood and wood products. And since you're 'skinning' a frame of wood you're in effect making a type of "torsion box", which are immensely strong and stiff in relation to their weight. My only real concern here would be the stated depth — that doesn't compute with the stated aim of using 2x4s. [contd]

Comment: A 2x4 is only nominally 2" thick, but the real thickness plus even one skin of OSB (and I presume you're skinning both sides) is obviously more than 1.5".

Comment: Cable and turnbuckles would also get you torsion if you wanted to trade mass for lighter hardware. You could use wood for the strength and stiffness in some axes, and maintain squareness using mechanical devices.

Comment: But I agree with Graphus here that huge designs like this are not a great fit. Maybe a question about a specific aspect of this build would be more focused and answerble.

Comment: I don't know, if this was a 7' x 8' oak table he was working on, everyone would be all  googoo-gaga about it. Probably not a good fit for [diy.se], either, so we may as well help out (until it comes to the metal working).

Comment: I am never googoo-gaga about anything. TRUTH.

Answer (score 1):

Metal is not necessary for this project.

You really only need solid sturdy wide gussets on the sides, and solid sturdy overall construction. 2x4's, **Plywood** sheathing.

Quality wheels wheels will make a huge difference.

I could write a long tutorial but photos will be better than words.

Here are a couple of shots of the art walls in my friends studio/gallery.

[image]

[image]